# changing view in storyboard remove all view's position

Tags: iphone

I found strange issue under storyboard;
I have dragged `UIImageView`, which passed to necessary frame inside `UIView` (and can return back). To do this, I subclassed `UIImageView` and changed frame inside touches delegates. Everything works if I don't change current view.

[image]

After view flipped and return back, I seen objects at a same positions, like nothing was happened before:

[image]

I can store internally all object's positions, but why iOS don't save all frame changes?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's likely that the view was released when you switched to a different view and reloaded when you switched back. The new view had new subviews, of course, and each of those was positioned according to the data in the storyboard or .xib file.

A cardinal rule in iOS development is that you shouldn't use views to store application state. If the positions of the views needs to be preserved, you should store those positions in the app's model. The view controller should implement the `-viewDidLoad` method to fetch the positions from the model and set the subviews accordingly.

Comment: so, u mention is i must stored all CGpoints of current UIView object in, for example, appdelegate properties, and when viewwillappear will called, restore it?

Comment: @user170317 Preferably not in properties of the app delegate directly, but in some distinct object that is the data model for your app (although it's not uncommon for the app delegate to have a reference to the model). Where does your app store the rest of its data? Wherever you store the information, the view controller will need to know how to find it. You can set up the subviews in -viewDidLoad or -viewWillAppear -- either should work fine.

Comment: looking like much more complicated than need. if i moving subview, a better solution will keep positions and don't move them out :). apple take care about do more coding for us :). anyway, tnx for explanation.